# Verticles multiple instances on cores

Tags: java, vert.x

I am new to Vertx and I have a doubt that unfortunately stackoverflow has not solved. I have ubuntu server with 2 cores and I want to use this code.

```
  @Override
  public void start() throws Exception {
    vertx.deployVerticle(StringName, new DeploymentOptions().setInstances(2));
  }
```

The above verticle is an http server of my personal website. The [doc](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_specifying_number_of_verticle_instances) says that

> This is useful for scaling easily across multiple cores. For example
>   you might have a web-server verticle to deploy and multiple cores on
>   your machine, so you want to deploy multiple instances to utilise all
>   the cores.

Ok fine, I have 2 cores in my intel processor and so I `setInstances(2)` for scaling.

---

Say that I wake up tomorrow and I want to add a verticle to manage database and other logic. I still have 2 cores. Which is the correct code?

**v1**

```
  @Override
  public void start() throws Exception {
    //2 instances of http server verticle
    vertx.deployVerticle(StringName, new DeploymentOptions().setInstances(2));
    //2 instances of database verticle
    vertx.deployVerticle(StringName, new DeploymentOptions().setInstances(2));
  }
```

**v2**

```
  @Override
  public void start() throws Exception {
    //1 instance of http server verticle
    vertx.deployVerticle(StringName, new DeploymentOptions().setInstances(1));
    //1 instance of database verticle
    vertx.deployVerticle(StringName, new DeploymentOptions().setInstances(1));
  }
```

So in other words I am asking this. Knowing that i have 2 cores; must the TOTAL SUM of the instance be 2 (so 1 http and 1 database)? Or 2 must be the max for each instance?

It is not a MUST actually but I want to do best practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no absolute answer to your question, it all depends on what each of your verticle does. You have to benchmark different settings to determine what's good for your particular use case.

Things you might consider in this process: if you have a "database" verticle, it is likely you will do some small processing (to reformat the data for example), while the http server verticle will only forward data over the eventbus. In this case perhaps having more database verticle instances will work better. But again, benchmark different settings before making a decision.